# C# Fields inside objects in a list being nulled out after LINQ WHERE

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, where-clause

```
 IEnumerable<Game> games = await _context.Games
            .Include(e => e.Challenger)
            .Include(e => e.Opponent)
            .Include(e => e.Winner)
            .ToListAsync();
```

When i query a table using Entity Framework 6 in .Net Core App, i get a list with the correct elements from the database, all looks good so far:

[So far so good img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3b8R.png)

`Challenger`, `Opponent` and `Winner` all has a Player object with the correct info for each.

Then i try to filter the data using `LINQ`:

```
            IEnumerable<Game> games = await _context.Games
            .Include(e => e.Challenger)
            .Include(e => e.Opponent)
            .Include(e => e.Winner)
            .ToListAsync();
    
        if (finished.HasValue)
        {
            games = games.Where(g => g.Finished == finished.Value);
        }
```

This is where weird stuff happens that i dont understand, some fields inside the objects in the list becomes nulled out:

[WTF img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7d3G.png)

As shown in the image, in the first element, `Opponent` and `Winner` are nulled out (and their ids)

In the second element `Challenger` and `Winner` are nulled out

And it kinda goes on randomly like that. Some objects has all three nulled out.

Tried to filter "manually" thinking LINQ was the problem:

```
if (finished.HasValue)
        {
            //games = games.Where(g => g.Finished == finished.Value);

            List<Game> newList = new List<Game>();
            foreach (var game in games)
            {
                if (game.Finished == finished.Value)
                {
                    newList.Add(game);
                }
            }
        }
```

But same result and it is driving me crazy. Am i missing something obvious that I'm not seeing?

Entities:

```
public class Game
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public int? ChallengerId { get; set; }
    public Player? Challenger { get; set; }
    public int? OpponentId { get; set; }
    public Player? Opponent { get; set; }
    public bool? Finished { get; set; }
    public int? WinnerId { get; set; }
    public Player? Winner { get; set; }
    public DateTime? GameDate { get; set; }
    public int? EloShift { get; set; }
}


public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? PlayerName { get; set; }
    public int? Wins { get; set; }
    public int? Losses { get; set; }
    public int? Rating { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your images are showing different games (see `Game.Id`) - are you sure e.g. that `Game.Id` == 7 isn't null?

Comment: I was sure as i had an id on all of them but something has happened to my database that nulled out these values. Thank you for your answer, it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, look at your data. On your screenshots, you can see next: an item with id = 3 has all the fields you need filled, but! it's Finished field is equal to "true" value

[image: first screenshot, not filtered]

Then on the second screenshot you can see that it's filtered by finished value equals to "false"
[image: second screenshot, filtered by finished == false]

Try  running the query like

```
    games = games.Where(g => g.Finished == true); //or .Where(g => g.Finished)
```

And you will probably see different results. Hope this will help

Comment: The reason why it is like this is because Finished is a query param that can be null or can be true or false, so i can get all games if null or finished/unfinished games. But the problem seems to be corrupted data in the database, no idea how they got corrupted but im looking into it. Thanks for the answer, it helped. Didn't look at the finished and id field when trying to solve this.